# Matlab: How to reduce this part of my program using a for loop and how to avoid the error message for union function?

Tags: matlab

How to reduce this part of my program using a for loop and how to avoid the error message for union function:

V1,V2,...,V10 are vectors with different lengths (size(Vj) different from size(Vk))

```
V1 = X(9, ismember(X(1,:), EE(1)));
V2 = X(9, ismember(X(1,:), EE(2)));
V3 = X(9, ismember(X(1,:), EE(3)));
V4 = X(9, ismember(X(1,:), EE(4)));
V5 = X(9, ismember(X(1,:), EE(5)));
V6 = X(9, ismember(X(1,:), EE(6)));
V7 = X(9, ismember(X(1,:), EE(7)));
V8 = X(9, ismember(X(1,:), EE(8)));
V9 = X(9, ismember(X(1,:), EE(9)));
V10 = X(9, ismember(X(1,:), EE(10)));
```

Zj is the union of all Vk except Vj:

```
Z1 = union(V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10);
Z2 = union(V1,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10);
Z3 = union(V1,V2,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10);
Z4 = union(V1,V2,V3,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10);
Z5 = union(V1,V2,V3,V4,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10);
Z6 = union(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V7,V8,V9,V10);
Z7 = union(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V8,V9,V10);
Z8 = union(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V9,V10);
Z9 = union(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V10);
Z10 = union(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9);

??? Error using ==> union
Too many input arguments.
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Schorsch: in my question, there is 2 problems helpful for other readers: 1- how to use a for loop on index, and 2- how to use the union function for several vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a MATLAB [cell](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) for different size vectors, and then just use a normal MATLAB [for loop](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/for.html):

```
%a cell V
V = cell(10,1);

for i=1:10
    %dummy data of different sizes
    V{i} = rand(i,1);
    %your data 
    %V{i} = X(9, ismember(X(1,:), EE(i)));
end
```

[Union is both associative and commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Algebraic_properties), therefore you can do a sequential union of pairs in any ordering and it will be the same as the union of all the things in one go:

```
Z = cell(10,1);
for i=1:10
  for j = 1:10
      if(i~=j)
          Z{i} =  union(V{j}, Z{i});
      end
  end
end
```